# SharePoint file share access issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We can access a SharePoint file share from our desktop (start run, \SPserver\share).

however, it says it cannot find the network path when we try to do this same thing from a server machine....any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Workstation service wasn't running this link will help you :
    http://computerstepbystep.com/workstation_service.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not good way to access it, I would rather map a drive with sharepoint url.
But before that, you have to make sure that WebClient feature is installed and running on the server.

Follow the instruction below to map a drive to sharepoint.

https://support.appriver.com/kb/a715/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-sharepoint.aspx